# node.js/mongoDB - How to manage ObjectIDs between clients and web-server

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Using Node.js 4.2.4 and mongoDB 3.2

Separation of Concerns - Keeping Clients Decoupled from mongoDB

**Problem:**

I'm use to the idea of sending out ids as strings from the server and reading them back as strings from the client - but with mongoDB's use of ObjectIDs I'm getting confused because logically it seems that - **to keep the clients decoupled from the database - there will need to be casting done on ObjectIDs and there string counterparts as they are shuttled back and forth between the client and the server.**

**Clarifying Questions :**

1) As data is shipped out the client I am assuming it's common to use ObjectIDs to map UI interactions to the data(e.g. user clicks a post). When doing so, **do I need to cast ObjectIDs to strings as they go client side and cast them back to ObjectIDs as they go back to the server side?**

2) **Should ALL key generation and casting(if needed) should all be happening server-side?**(either coupled with node server or a layer between the database and the web-server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Yes.

2) Yes.

An `ObjectId` can be cast to string for transport (usually JSON) and back to an `ObjectId` when you need to query the database. The client only has to know it's some arbitrary string representing an object.

Comment: So if I am sending out a JSON representation of a document that contains an ObjectID and embeddedDocuments with ObjectIDs - then will I need logic that knows what the document structure will be and manually change the _ids to strings before converting the document to JSON?

Comment: IMPORTANT note for anyone reading. If you send out your response as JSON you will notice that your ObjectID automatically are casted into strings.

Comment: If you use Mongoose, you can use `doc.toJSON()`, but the native `JSON.stringify()` will not work.

Answer (score 1):

Using npm [bson-util](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bson-util) could be a proper way to send bson data to the client. Also you can parse the data in client as bson again.

```html
import {parse, stringify} from 'bson-util';

let a = {b: new ObjectID()};
 
stringify(a); 
// {"b":{"$oid":"5e32849068f40e424a80fe42"}}
 
parse('{"b":{"$oid":"5e32849068f40e424a80fe42"}}'); 
// {b: ObjectID("5e32849068f40e424a80fe42")}
```